# Flask session not available between routes although is persisted on file system

Tags: python, flask, session

I am using session in my Flask application and seems to be able to save the values into it and retrieve in the same route but not in other routes

I have the following in my Flask app defining Flask session:

```
from flask import Response, Flask
from flask import request, render_template, jsonify
from flask import session
from flask_session import Session
app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = secrets.token_hex(16)
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
app.config['SESSION_FILE_DIR'] = './session-data'  
Session(app)
CORS(app)
```

and then

```
@app.route('/save_item')
def save_item():
    session['item'] = 233
```

and :

```
@app.route('/get_item')
def get_item():
    print(session.items()). # why this is empty?!
    item = session.get('item') # or session['item']. none works
```

there are files created under the defined session directory which contain the item after it was saved by /save_item and yet it can not be retrieved by /get_item.

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance